# Combining elements of an array into pairs in Java

Tags: java

I'm doing this exercise, where's given the array T [N] with natural numbers (integers) . And I need to build a program to present on the screen all possible pairs of elements of table T. The program must contain a function (method). For example T = (1,2,3,4) the possible pairs are (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4)

This is the code that I've done this far, but it doesn't show all the pairs, only the first ones. Can someone help me where I'm wrong? What should I add?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Give the number of elements of the array: ");
    int N = in.nextInt();
    
    int [] T = new int [N];
    
    System.out.println("Please give " + N + " elements: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < T.length; i++)
        T[i] = in.nextInt();
        
    System.out.println("The array is = " + Arrays.toString(T));

    pairs(T);
}

public static void pairs (int [] T) {
    int nr = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<T.length-1; i++) {
        System.out.println(T[i] + "," + T[i+1]);
    nr++;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Terrible title. Click « Edit » link, rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: done Basil, sorry i'm new here

Comment: In your loop, you only pair elements at index `i` and `i+1`. So of array `T`, element 0 and 1 get paired; then 1 and 2 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This should be done using nested loops:

```java
static void printPairs(int ... arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i] + ", " + arr[j]);
        }
    }
}

printPairs(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Output:

```
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
2, 3
2, 4
3, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get unique pairs of elements from the source list. If you heard about stream and generics you can use something like that

```
public static <T> List<Pair<T, T>> getUniquePair(final List<T> source) {
    int[] count = new int[1];
    return source.stream()
            .peek((s) -> count[0]++)
            .flatMap(
                    inSource -> source.stream()
                            .skip(count[0])
                            .map(innSource -> Pair.of(inSource, innSource))
            )
            .filter(pair -> notEqual(pair.getFirst(), pair.getSecond()))
            .collect(toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Henri Koka your code has a simple logical flaw. In the method `void pairs(int[] T)`:

```
public static void pairs (int [] T)
{
    int nr = 0;
    
    for (int i=0; i<T.length-1; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(T[i] + "," + T[i+1]);
        nr++;
    }
}
```

Lets make a quick dry run. You have used a for loop from `i = 0` to `T.length - 1`. You have successfully printed all the ***consecutive pairs***. The reason being you only used one loop. You have to use **two loops**. Here is the correct code:

```
public static void pairs (int [] T)
{
    int nr = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0;i < T.length-1;i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1;j < T.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(T[i] + "," + T[j]);
            nr++;
        }
    }
}
```

I will share another way to understand the fact why we use two loops. In this code, we have to find pairs.

> INPUT:  (1,2,3,4)

> OUTPUT: (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4)

*What you did was that you printed (T[0], T[0+1]), (T[1], T[1+1]), ...*

What we actually need is (**T[0]**, T[1]), (**T[0]**, T[2]),....
then (**T[1]**, T[2]), (**T[1]**, T[3]),... and so on.

The x part of (x, y) will increment only when we are finished with all the following y.

I hope I have helped you.

Comment: This was so specificly explained, thank you a lot!